# Unterschied zwischen "Rufnummer" und "Telefonnummer"?

Tags: difference

Gibt es einen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen Rufnummer und Telefonnummer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nein, *Rufnummer* ist lediglich eine formellere Bezeichnung für eine Telefonnummer.

Answer (score 2):

"Rufnummer" literally means "call number."  "Telefonnummer""" is, of course, just a telephone number.

In the appropriate context, they are synonymous.

Comment: Both terms are conventionalized (hence opaque), that means a single one of the many possible meaning structures that compounds can have in German is commonly expected. Still, both could have other, transparent “literal” meanings in certain contexts, e.g. where calls are counted or where a telephone plays an important part in a sexual act.